# Render layer node only renders on frame 1 when Render Animation is run

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I was following the Donut tutorial and backtracked to do compositing. However, when I try render animation -> the composite is applied on frame 1 but then TAKES OVER for the rest of the render frames.

1. Frame 1: Donut and composite background
2. Frame 2-300: Composite background only.

Here's the image snippet of the render animation output.
[image: File output where composite takes over animation frames]

Apologies, new to blender. Using blender version 3.3.1
Blend file: [image]

Comment: ok, that's really weird, i just rendered out your animation to frame 5 and it worked: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgzhj.png but ...you didn't changed the output file and look at the right directory?

Comment: Definitely the right folder, I've re-rendered a few animation sequences to double check render location. BTW, I'm using Cycles to render

Comment: Attempted another Render, same result. I have 'Transparent' enabled in my Cycles setting, which sets the Render Layer node to a completely transparent view after an Image render, which indicates Blender is rendering the composite nodes (pink) and a transparent Render Layer over the top after frame 1. Does that sound like expected behaviour?

Comment: I've rendered the complete animation, all 300 frames, every rendered frame is composited over the background.

Comment: What colour settings do you have? Under Output settings>Output>Colour

Answer (score 0):

So I added a View Layer to the project (which is the top right drop down in blender 3.3.1) and this has 'fixed' the problem.

Seems that the Render Layer node was being overwritten each time a frame was rendered, causing some weird affect where the Render Layer node image became transparent from Frame 2.